# Subset data for the most recent month

Tags: r

I have a .txt file

```
test.txt
V1 V2 Date
A B 2020-01-02
C D 2020-02-27
E F 2020-09-10
G H 2020-09-15
```

I want to subset data based on the most recent month.
I did this which does the job but I want to extract the most recent month automatically rather than typing in manually and then extract the data

```
test$month <- factor(format(test$Date, "%B"),levels = month.name)
test.subset <- test[test$month == "September"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `arrange` the `Date` class column and `filter` the `format`ed value by comparing it with the `last` one

```
library(dplyr)
test %>%
   mutate(Date = as.Date(Date), Month = format(Date, '%B')) %>% 
   arrange(Date) %>%
   filter(Month == last(Month)) %>%
   select(-Month)
```

-output

```
#  V1 V2       Date
#1  E  F 2020-09-10
#2  G  H 2020-09-15
```

#### data

```
test <- structure(list(V1 = c("A", "C", "E", "G"), V2 = c("B", "D", "F", 
"H"), Date = c("2020-01-02", "2020-02-27", "2020-09-10", "2020-09-15"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option using `subset` + `gsub`

```
subset(
  transform(
    df,
    ym = gsub("\\d+$", "", Date)
  ),
  ym == max(ym),
  select = -ym
)
```

which gives

```
  V1 V2       Date
3  E  F 2020-09-10
4  G  H 2020-09-15
```

---

A `data.table` option

```
setDT(df)[
  ,
  `:=`(Year = year(as.IDate(Date)), Month = month(as.Date(Date)))
][
  .(max(Year), max(Month)),
  on = .(Year, Month)
][
  ,
  `:=`(Year = NULL, Month = NULL)
][]
```

gives

```
   V1 V2       Date
1:  E  F 2020-09-10
2:  G  H 2020-09-15
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(V1 = c("A", "C", "E", "G"), V2 = c("B", "D", "F", 
"H"), Date = c("2020-01-02", "2020-02-27", "2020-09-10", "2020-09-15"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the structure shared by @ThomasIsCoding, and assuming the year is constant, one could just look for the row with the max month and filter for that:

```
# using datatable
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[month(as.IDate(Date)) == max(month(as.IDate(Date)))]

    V1 V2       Date
1:  E  F 2020-09-10
2:  G  H 2020-09-15
```